# How do i compare to Columns and return a number automatically : Example: =IFS(AND(B2="Groups",N2="Blood Donation"),4)

Tags: google-sheets

How do i compare to Columns and return a number automatically : Example: =IFS(AND(B2="Groups",N2="Blood Donation"),4)

I tried using Arrayformula but it returns N/A but without Array it works fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use multiplication:

```
=IFS((B2:B="Groups")*(N2:N="Blood Donation"),4)
```

Comment: =IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A),IFS((B2:B="Individual")*(N2:N="Blood Donation")*(V2:V <> "")*(U2:U="Full day")*(U2:U="Half day",8)))))

I wanted displaying 16 when full day and 8 when half day but it fails

Comment: Try: ```=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A),(B2:B="Individual")*(N2:N="Blood Donation")*(V2:V <> "")*(((U2:U="Full day")*2)+(U2:U="Half day"))*8)),"")```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF((B2:B="Groups")*(N2:N="Blood Donation"), 4, ))
```

Comment: =IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A),INDEX(IF((B2:B="Individual")*(N2:N="Blood Donation")*(V2:V <> "")*(U2:U="Full day"), 16,)*(U2:U="Half day"), 8,),)))

Returns 0, when tried in this structure

Comment: @KingMichaelKing share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result